# Add A Gallery - Android

Tags: android

How can I dynamically add a gallery to an android app, I have:

```
Gallery gallery = new Gallery(this);
```

But it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the Layout parameters of gallery, ie size then take a Layout and add into it

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
gallery.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

LinearLayout mLinearLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewByID(R.id....);
mLinearLayout.addView(gallery);
```

Comment: Doesnt work, runtime exception